How to add a variable load to a 120VAC circuit
We have a lighting system that uses a 1995-vintage Lutron GRAFIK Eye GRX-3004 control unit. We've replaced as many bulbs as possible with LEDs and one of the zones flickers. Although there are settings for different load types, the control unit was made before LED bulbs were available so there's no setting for that. Replacing the control unit is very expensive so I'm trying to figure out a way to fix the problem without doing that.
I think the basic issue is that the three LED bulbs on that zone don't create a sufficient load to avoid the flickering. I'm wondering if there's some way to add a load to the circuit to get it to where it doesn't flicker. Since I don't know what the load needs to be, I'd like it to be variable so I can add the minimum load necessary. The lights in question are pendant lights and there is crawlspace above them so whatever I add doesn't have to be pretty. But I'd rather it didn't generate much heat or noise.
I don't know a lot about electronics but I can wield a soldering iron and follow a simple circuit diagram. Any bright ideas?

fwiw, i've used an ac/dc adapter (an old, heavy one) to remove the flickers in the same situation. I didn't actually have a load on the DC side of the adapter, just it's mere presence was enough. I liked it because it didn't generate heat, and in theory at least, didn't cause my electric meter to spin like a resistive load would. Barring that, a strand of old xmas lights using 120v bulbs can be used to create a relatively cool and highly tunable (screw bulbs in and out) dummy load.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You might not know that Lutron sells a capacitor in their residential line, to help with this problem. It is meant to increase the current flowing through the dimmer. You put it in parallel with the lights.  You could try this device, or temporarily diy if you are an electronics person.

In a similar circumstance, I've put two 4-watt incandescent night-light lamps in series, and then put that load in parallel across a flickering LED. That wastes 2 watts while the lamp is on, though.
If the LED's are easily replaceable, e.g., standard screw base, then first try some different brands of lamps, specifically one that is stated to be dimmable. If that doesn't resolve the issue, then try putting a night-light in parallel, as described. They barely glow when in series, though, so it doesn't qualify as "a bright idea."
N.B. Though the lamps dissipate very little power, make sure that the installation cannot start fire (e.g., if confined under insulation) and is electrically safe.

This is helpful. I have three LED lamps in parallel. So when you say "put that load in parallel across a flickering LED," how exactly would I do that? Are you saying to do one of these loads for each lamp or to do one of these loads across just the first lamp? And by "across" do you mean that the hot source line connects to the hot terminals of the lamp and the series load and the neutral source line connects to the neutral terminals? I know these are rudimentary questions but as I said, I don't know a lot about this.

If the lamps are in parallel, only one small, additional, resistive load (2 to 4 W incandescent lamp) is needed. By "parallel", it means wired across the lamps, to hot and to neutral. That said, if you have these questions, you might be better served by having a licensed electrician. install it.

Well, I tried the lamps in series and it worked! And I didn't burn the house down. Thanks for your help!
